# How to apply theories of line bundles to arbitrary bundles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles

Many concepts in geometry apply a priori specifically to line bundles. For certain theories like ampleness, nef, positivity I know that in order to generalize to arbitrary ranked vector bundles $E\to X$  we use the tautological line bundle $\mathcal{O}_E(-1)\to \mathbb{P}(E)$ over the projectivization of $E$. My questions are the following

- Are there other theories for which we also use $\mathcal{O}_E(-1)\to \mathbb{P}(E)$?
- "Why" does this technique work? In other words what essential characteristics of $E$ are captured in $\mathcal{O}_E(-1)$?
- Are there other ways to reduce a vector bundle to a line bundle and if yes for which concepts?

Comment: Atiyah thought about vector bundles on elliptic curves by finding subbundles and quotient bundles until you get down to line bundles.

Comment: Your third bullet point is the [splitting principle.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/21370/where-does-the-splitting-principle-come-from-and-does-it-generalize)

Comment: @BranimirĆaćić, the third bullet point is "Are there other ways …?"  Did you [mean](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/413582/how-to-apply-theories-of-line-bundles-to-arbitrary-bundles#comment1060394_413582) the second bullet point?

Comment: Argh, you’re absolutely right. #2 is the splitting principle, #3 is whether or not there are other techniques like the splitting principle.

Comment: I don't mean to be too pick but for positivity etc. you need $\mathcal{O}_E(+1)$ and depending on your convention, you need to work with $\mathbb{P}(E)$ or  $\mathbb{P}(E^\vee)$. The key point is that you want $\pi_*\mathcal{O}_E(1)=E$. This partly answers why it works.

Comment: In topology (and in motivic homotopy), the splitting principle can be formalized by a result of Segal's from "The stable homotopy of complex projective space": the space BU (classifying virtual complex vector bundles) splits off QCP^infty = Loops^oo Susp^oo_+(CP^infty). This latter thing is to be understood as the free E_oo-space on CP^infty, so is sth like "formal homotopical sums of line bundles". This lets you recover the homology+cohomology of BU from knowledge about the homology+cohomology of CP^infty, etc. (But if you replace CP^oo with CP^n, you have to replace BU with Loops SU(n+1).)